# Error when trying to drop table in synapse dedicated pool stored procedure

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

I'm trying to create the following stored procedure in Synapse dedicated pool to check if a table exists and if it does I want to make the staging table the new main table by renaming it, and if it doesn't exist then just change the name of the staging to be a main table.

I'm getting an incorrect syntax error when I'm trying to drop the original main table:

> Parse error at line: 15, column: 20: Incorrect syntax near '@DedicatedTable'

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RenameStagingTableToMainTable
    (@StagingTable VARCHAR(MAX),
     @DedicatedTable VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    -- Check if the main table exists
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE object_type = 'U' AND name = @DedicatedTable)
    BEGIN
        -- Rename the staging table to the main table
        EXEC sp_rename @StagingTable, @DedicatedTable

        -- Drop the existing main table
        DROP TABLE @DedicatedTable
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- The main table does not exist, so rename the staging table to the main table
        EXEC sp_rename @StagingTable, @DedicatedTable
    END
END
```